# B-tree on varchar column with Non-cluster index

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can anybody explain me how a B-tree formed on a varhcar (name) column having non-cluster index on it.
It will be better if anyone suggest it with diagram.
Or how this query work with this column 
select * from table1
where name like '%abc%'

My main concern is that when a tree will be form on the root node what value it will save first character of name or somthing else and how it will move to child node to required data.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're actually asking - but a query `like '%abc%'`will not be able to use a index/tree because it start with anything and everything; so it will always have to scan through each row/leaf note.

Comment: Thank you for yor reply. May I know how a tree structure will form for this column. Like what value will be stored on Root node and child node.

Comment: A b-tree algorithmically only cares that it's keys are comparable. Strings are comparable just like ints are.